Rails 7 devise gem can't login with valid credentials after some days
Rails 7
Devise 4.9.4 (with bcrypt (~> 3.0))
User can't login error raised "Invalid Email or password."
User reset password and can login with new password after some days he/she can't login again have to reset password again
Note:

There is no password expiry settings
Checked from rails console with u.valid_password?('USER_PASSWORD') => false
User has encrypted_password field of type string

Checked manual encryption of new password via BCrypt::Password.create(new_password) and from user.encrypted_password it doesn't match
BCrypt::Password.create(new_password) == user.encrypted_password => false

Any chance you are changing your rails secret when deploying the application?

@dbugger Thank you so much for responding, This issue also happens at Development ENV
We don't change secret

You either have a configuration issue or the passwords are being updated unexpectedly

Check your credentials by using rails credentials:show for each environment.
